# How should I refer to a MySQL server on a web host?

Tags: php, mysql, ip-address, web-hosting

When using PHP to connect to a MySQL database on a web host, what is the best way to refer to the server?

The MySQL admin page on my web host says what the IP address of the server is, but can I use something else other than the IP number?

Eg.

```
$con = mysql_connect("l00.50.10.10","user","password");
if (!$con) { die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); }
```

When I use `localhost` I get this output:

> Could not connect: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
>   '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

Comment: It is much more common to use "localhost" if your PHP code is on the same server as the database.

Comment: Maybe it's failing because you have a lowercase L instead of a digit 1? ;)

Comment: @ElYobo PDO and mysqli both have their pros and cons; I wouldn't say either is necessarily better than the other.

Comment: @Vulcan, so long as the OP uses one or the other they'll be in a much better place :)  I can't think of many cases in which MySQLi would be a better choice, but I guess there are some of them.

Comment: I think beginner should start with mysqli. There are more tutorials and examples with mysqli_ in many languages available. PDO is rather for more experienced programmers, when mysqli is not enough.

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to the script's system with "localhost" as the host.

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "password");
```

However, connecting to the IP is most likely failing because you have a lowercase L where you should have a one digit (but I'm hoping the IP in the question was just an example).

Also, use mysqli or PDO instead of mysql, which is on the verge of deprecation.

Comment: If host provider use seperate servers for Database and Web, this wont work

Comment: @Svetlio Valid point although it's likely they're on the same server.  Either way, I've added my comment about `l` versus `1` into my answer. Thanks.

Comment: When I use `localhost` I get this output: `Could not connect: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)`

Comment: @CJ7 Try using `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` to force the connection to use TCP/IP. Also, make sure that MySQL is running.

Answer (score 0):

You can the database server's host name, e.g. `mydbbox.example.com`. Using the IP address may be faster, as no DNS lookup will be necessary.

Also see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356893/is-it-faster-to-connect-use-mysql-at-localhost-instead-of-a-domain-even-if-the).

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question depends on how your host (or their control panel) configures MySQL privileges. The privileges are IP or hostname specific, so often connecting by IP or by hostname may not have the same connection results. If in doubt, I would stick to exactly the settings they give you.

Read more: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/account-names.html

Comment: All I can see on the MySQL admin page is the IP address of the server, but I am reluctant to use it because they might change it without notice.

Comment: That is a valid concern. In that case, I would ask your host if they have a stable hostname that you can use that will connect to the same server with the same permissions.

Answer (score 0):

If database host is same computer - use `localhost`. MySQL will connect by local socket, not tcpip (network) when you use `localhost` with port number or not.

Sometimes server does not support socket connections, and you will get error like this:

> Could not connect: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket ...

**EDIT/CORRECTED:**
If you cant connect by socket - use `127.0.0.1`. It will force conncetion by tcpip.

If database server is installed on other machine - you can use `IP address` or `domain`.

IP address is better in most cases, because connection can be established even when DNS (domain name server) is not working correctly or when domain expired.

---

And one advice - **use mysqli_ instead of mysql_ functions** in new application. New functions are very similar in use, but more secure.

Old **mysql_ functions** are obsolete and they are **not recommended** for new applications. They are still available in PHP, because of compatibility with old, outdated software (CMS systems, e-commerce systems etc

[PHP Help](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) says (about mysql_connect):

> Use of this extension is discouraged. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL
>   extension should be used.

---

**More about connecting with localhost** - info from [MySQL Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connecting.html)

> On Unix, MySQL programs treat the host name localhost specially, in a
>   way that is likely different from what you expect compared to other
>   network-based programs. For connections to localhost, MySQL programs
>   attempt to connect to the local server by using a Unix socket file.
>   This occurs even if a --port or -P option is given to specify a port
>   number. To ensure that the client makes a TCP/IP connection to the
>   local server, use --host or -h to specify a host name value of
>   127.0.0.1

Note, that "--port" and "-P" options are decribed in other context than PHP, but connection mechanism works similar and `localhost` is "special" name, doesnt matter is this PHP, console or some other software.

Comment: When I use `localhost` I get this output: `Could not connect: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)`

Comment: Try 127.0.0.1 and read my extended answer. I explained why it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to type in google something like this?

> php Could not connect: Can't connect to local MySQL server through
>   socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

Answer (score -1):

This depends mostly on how your host has things configured. From my experience you will use "localhost", the server's IP address or a subdomain of some sort set up by the host.

I'd start by testing "localhost" as this is the default for most shared hosting environments.

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password");
```