# Is typing the db url as localhost faster than giving remote server address?

Tags: spring-boot

I was wondering if typing remote server url instead of typing localhost in spring boot properties db url (spring.datasource.url) is slower? Let's say I am running spring boot application on server with IPv4 123.123.12.12, will typing

`jdbc:mariadb://123.123.12.12:3306/dbname`

make it slower than

`jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/dbname` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you access `localhost`, your `/etc/hosts` file will tell your computer not to look any further and redirects you to your own computer. When you access the `IP address`, your computer will ask the `router to fetch the data`, and your router will then point back to your computer.

---

Directly using the IP address of any interface on the localhost - either the loopback interface (127.0.0.1) or any other - is the option with the absolutely best performance. The packets will be actually routed through the loopback interface (no matter which IP is actually used) at - practically - CPU speed.

There are three reasons, however, to prefer 127.0.0.1 over the IPs of the other interfaces:

- The loopback interface is crucial to the operation of the system and
  as such it is initialized very early in the boot process and nearly
  always available.
- It is not affected by external factors: while removing the eth0 cable
  will not by itself interrupt localhost's access to itself via eth0's
  IP, it will mess things up if you have any of the many
  "autoconfiguration" systems that will happily shutdown the interface
  on link loss.
- If you have a firewall setup, it's quite possible that the rule chain
  is longer (and thus slightly worse performance-wise) when the IPs of
  the public interfaces are involved.

[Loopback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost), [Also Refer This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356893/is-it-faster-to-connect-use-mysql-at-localhost-instead-of-a-domain-even-if-the)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, setting up `IP` or `DNS` are slower than localhost. In case of localhost, application does not need to verify anything. It will directly try to connect the database on same server. But in case of `IP` and `DNS`, it first need to check that provided url is valid and then will connect to database.

Comment: Thank you Tayyab Razaq for your answer, this is what i needed.